# How to use different text colours for different overflow menu items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 menu items in my overflow menu and I want the text for each of these items to have a different colour of my choice (based on the resources within my app - e.g. ). How can I achieve this? The code below changes the text of all items to blue (which is not what I want). I only want one of them to be blue, the second to be red, and the third to be green.

```
<style name="ThemeCustom">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>        
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the menu item to your overflow menu, modify the foreground color of your menu item text while preparing the options in your java file.

For example, in the OnPrepareOptions menu method, get the title of the menu item and modify the foreground color for each menu items

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(itemID);
        String title = mi.getTitle().toString();
        Spannable newTitle = new SpannableString(title);        
        newTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, newTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(newTitle);

    return true;
}
```

You can iterate it over a for loop to get the list of menu items and change each title sets' foreground color.